# How can I Animate instantly in React native

Tags: react-native, animation

I am starting animated using 'onPanResponderMove' to move the animated view whenever the user is holding down the button

```
onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
  if (withinbounds(gestureState.moveX, xOffset + buttonSize, xOffset + buttonSize * 2)) {
    this.setState({y: this.state.y + 1});
    Animated.timing(
    this.state.layerOffset,
    {toValue: {x: 0, y: (this.state.y * gridSize}, easing: Easing.in(Easing.ease)},
  ).start();
  }
}
```

Which is being used to set the offset of a view

```
<Animated.View style={{position: 'absolute', left: this.state.layerOffset.x, top: this.state.layerOffset.y}}>
  <Grid  />
</Animated.View>
```

However, the way this is currently working, the animated view will not move until The button is stopped being press, how can I make the animation start immediately, instead of waiting for the button to no-longer be pressed although this.state.y is continually updated.

Answer (score 1):

When playing around with `PanResponder` the way to go is usually using `Animated.event` instead of `Animated.timing`. Here's some [doc](https://animationbook.codedaily.io/animated-event/) that might help you out.

When using `Animated.timing` you should provide a duration, which you haven't done in this case. The difference between the two is that `Animated.timing` will change a value over a certain period of time whereas `Animated.event` instantly sets the value which is what you want.

Comment: I can see how Animated.event would work if the object I want to animate is the same object that has the 'onPanResponderMove' but they are separate objects. How can I use Animated.event, given it is on a separate object and I don't want to use the 'gestureState arg' in my Animated.ValueXY ?